# Имеют ли смысл указатели на функции класса?

Tags: c++, классы, функции, указатели

Недавно столкнулся с одной непонятной для меня вещью - указатели на функции класса.
Имеют ли они смысл? В каких случаях используются?
Пример:

```
class ABC
{
public:
    void show()
    {
        cout << "Hello" << endl;
    }
};
int main()
{
    void(ABC::*point)() = &ABC::show; // указатель на ф-цию класса
    ABC myClass;
    (myClass.*point)();

    return 0;
}
```

Такие указатели работают только с объектом.
Разве не удобнее вызывать функции класса напрямую?

```
ABC myClass;
myClass.show();
```

Или

```
ABC myClass;
ABC * point2 = &myClass;
point2->show();
```

Comment: Ну с таким же успехом можно спросить, зачем вообще нужны указатели, если "удобнее обращаться к указуемым сущностям напрямую".

Comment: В Qt сигналы и слоты реализованы примерно таким образом.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Когда заранее известно какая функция должна вызываться, безусловно, проще использовать явный вызов без каких-то дополнительных указателей. Но не всегда это так. Проблему можно рассматривать в том же смысле, что и указатели на объекты. Т.е. если мы знаем какой объект использовать, то и переменная-указатель на объект нам не нужна, а если такой объект заранее неизвестен, то нужно использовать указатель. Так же и с указателем на функцию. Причем по-большому счету не важно член, или нечлен. Наличие подобных указателей просто добавляет необходимый уровень косвенности в программу.

Answer (score 2):

Да. Мы можем сложить указатели в map, либо ещё куда-то и динамически определять, какая функция должна вызываться. При этом способ вызова останется прежним.

http://ideone.com/zdYvce

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class ABC
{
public:
    void f1() { cout << "#1" << endl; }
    void f2() { cout << "#2" << endl; }
};

int main()
{
    void (ABC::*f[])() = {&ABC::f1, &ABC::f2};
    ABC myClass;
    int x;

    while(cin >> x)
        (myClass.*f[x&1])();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Скажите пожалуйста, что означает [x & 1]   ?
Я так понял, что если x - четный, то вызывается f1 , если нечетый - то вызывается f2.

Comment: @aleshka-batman да. Это такая проверка на нечетность.